# Thunderbird cannot decrypt message even though it has the private key

Tags: thunderbird, gpu, enigmail

I have sent an encrypted email and a CC to myself, also encrypted, using Thunderbird as email client and the hotmail SMTP server for delivery.

I have then received the email message and at first Thunderbird said it was
broken, but then repaired and decrypted it. I then saved the message to a local folder and now Thunderbird cannot decrypt it anymore. It displays an error message:

```
Enigmail Security Info Error - no matching private/secret key found
to decrypt message gpg: decryption failed: No secret key Note:
The message is encrypted for the following User ID's / Keys: ...,
0x ... (Name <address>)
```

The private key mentioned in the message is in my gpg database and has the correct email address associated with it. It is the same key pair I used to encrypt the message.

What could be the cause of the problem? Can it be that the hotmail SMTP or POP server corrupts gpg-encrypted messages in such a way as to make them unreadable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gpg version older than 2.1.0, problem might be with cypher algorithm CAST5 which produce not MDC-protected message.

Enigmail from version 2.0.4 don't decrypt such emails:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/versions/

Solution is to upgrade gpg. To read older emails, use parameter --no-mdc-warning as "Additional parameters for GnuPG" in the Enigmail preferences (advanced tab).

edit: from Enigmail 2.0.5 this workaround doesn't work.
For latest news check Enigmail forum (e.g. how to fix your public key if it's too old):
https://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/forum/support/thread/03ebee57/